# Testing that delete is correctly rolled back with DataIntegrityViolationException junit, spring, @Transactional

Tags: spring, junit, transactions

I have a category -> subCategory -> products hierarchy in my application. If a subcategory has no products, you are allowed to delete it. If a subCategory has products, the DAO throws a DataIntegrityViolationException and the transaction should be rolled back.

In my tests, I have:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestTransactionManagement.class})
public class BusinessSubCategoryCRUDTest {
  @Autowired
  public void setCRUD(BusinessSubCategoryCRUD crud) {
    this.crud = crud;
  }

  //  @Transactional
  @Test
  public void testDeleteBusinessSubCategoryInUseCanNotBeDeleted() {
    final long id = 1;
    BusinessSubCategory subCategoryBeforeDelete =
        crud.readBusinessSubCategory(id);
    final int numCategoriesBeforeDelete =
        subCategoryBeforeDelete.getBusinessCategories().size();

    try {
      crud.deleteBusinessSubCategory(
          new BusinessSubCategory(id, ""));
    } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
      System.err.println(e);
    }
    BusinessSubCategory subCategoryAfterDeleteFails =
        crud.readBusinessSubCategory(id);
    // THIS next assertion is the source of my angst. 
    // At this point the the links to the categories will have been
    // been deleted, an exception will have been thrown but the
    // Transaction is not yet rolled back if the test case (or test
    // class) is marked with @Transactional
    assertEquals(
        numCategoriesBeforeDelete,
        subCategoryAfterDeleteFails.getBusinessCategories().size());
  }
}
```

However, if I uncomment the @Transactional above @Test, it fails. I think the DAO is using the transaction from the @Test and so the transaction doesn't roll back until AFTER I check to be sure the transaction has been rolled back.

```
  @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation =
      Propagation.REQUIRED)
  public boolean deleteBusinessSubCategory(
      BusinessSubCategory businessSubCategory) {
    BeanPropertySqlParameterSource paramMap = new
        BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(businessSubCategory);
    namedJdbcTemplate.update(
        DELETE_CATEGORY_SUB_CATEGORY_BY_ID_SQL,
        paramMap);
    return 0 != namedJdbcTemplate.update(
        DELETE_SUB_CATEGORY_BY_ID_SQL, 
        paramMap);
  }
```

So, how do I have the DAO code still inherit the transaction from the context it is running in (in production it inherits the transaction from the service it is running in) but still be able to test it. I want to put @Transactional on the entire test class, but that then leaves my test either failing or incomplete.

For completeness, here is my configuration class for the test.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class TestTransactionManagement {
  @Bean
  public EmbeddedDatabase getDataSource() {
    EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
    EmbeddedDatabase db = builder
        .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL) //.H2 or .DERBY
        .addScript("sql/create-db.sql")
        .addScript("sql/create-test-data.sql")
        .build();
    return db;
  }


  @Bean
  public DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(getDataSource());
  }

  @Bean
  public BusinessSubCategoryCRUD getCRUD() {
    return new BusinessSubCategoryCRUD(getDataSource());
  }
}
```

Comment: _if I uncomment the Transactional above @Test, it fails_  . Where does it fail ? (there are 4 assertions in your test)

Comment: The last assertion fails...when it reads the subCategories out of the DB the categories have been deleted and so it expects 1 category and finds 0

Comment: I edited out the other assertions to clarify the issue. Thanks @ben75

Comment: Are you using AspectJ based transaction management or Spring proxy based?

Comment: Or, if you don't know the answer to my previous question, you can tell it by breaking on Spring's `TransactionManagementConfigurationSelector.selectImports(...)` method and report back which branch of the switch statement is chosen at runtime.

Comment: Given that I didn't change the defaults, I assume it is Spring's proxy based Transactions. I'll try to figure out for sure....

Comment: I have no clue. I'm not sure the piece I printed out is useful!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101021/discussion-between-nandor-elod-fekete-and-tim-perry).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "solution" or workaround was to reset the database before each test. Then there was no need for an @Transactional on the test, the rollback could be tested, and the test suite ran slighly slower due to the additional database setup.

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    Connection conn = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource);
    ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(
        conn, new ClassPathResource("sql/create-test-data.sql"));
    DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(conn, dataSource);
}
```